# Mortal Kombat 11 DLL issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation, dll, game-development, monogame

Getting Unarc.dll returned an error code: -12 while downloading MK 11 from DODI repacks even after installing all the redistributable files. Tried multiple ways like disabling the windows defender, increasing the virtual ram but no luck

Any fix for the issue

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear, what relationship is there between Unity, game development and MK11? Isn't that a game made using Unreal Engine?

Comment: Just want to unpack it

Comment: This is a forum dedicated to programming and application development. If you have a question regarding this game specifically, maybe it'd be better to post it on the MK 11 forums, not here.